# Customizing the Material UI 1.3.1 Expansion Panel

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, styling

I have the background image on the header, but when I open it up the image continues to the body. Is there a way to have the expanded text not have the same background as the header? Thanks in advance!

```
const styles = theme => ({
    expansion: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${Tuesday})`,
        width: "100%"
    },
    head: {
        height: '84px'
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: '32px',
        fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-Heavy'
    },
    body: {
        backgroundImage: 'none'
    }
});

const ExpandedMenu = (props) => {
const { classes } = props;
return(
    <div>
        <ExpansionPanel className={classes.expansion}>
            <ExpansionPanelSummary className={classes.head} expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
            <Typography className={classes.text}>TUESDAY</Typography>
            </ExpansionPanelSummary>
            <ExpansionPanelDetails className={classes.body}>
            <Typography className={classes.body}>
                <p>example text</p>
            </Typography>
            </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
     </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `withStyles`?

Comment: Yes, my issue now is that when it expands, the body still has the backgroundImage. I have updated the code if you have any insight!

Answer (score 2):

just give the `backGroundImage` to your `.head` class:

[this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o7plz69yzq) is the one that @SumanKundu built and I changed it to satisfy your need.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add inline styles but as @TFischer said withStyles will be a better option.

You can go to this sandbox for a working example and check if it works for you: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/03x2r4lw2w

Comment: Is there a way to only have the header have the background image instead of when it expands, the text area inherits the background?